Inside Virtuoso named graphs can RDF String literals be represented in different encodings?
Can it be a case when using two different implementations of TTL bulk loading to naming graphs in Virtuoso, string literals are represented in different encodings and can not be compared directly without explicit str() conversion?
The actual problem is the following.
One named graph <urn:model1> was populated using a custom JENA-based app.
The second graph <urn:model2> was populated using native Virtuoso Uploading from the web admin console.
Both graphs have a triple —
m:ID1111 m:reflect "ROAM-1234".

However the following query returns empty result —
select DISTINCT ?s ?s2 ?o
WHERE { 
    GRAPH <urn:model1>
    {
        ?s m:reflect ?o.
    }
    GRAPH <urn:model2>
    {
        ?s2 m:reflect ?o.
    }
}

— while a modification with explicit str and FILTER works as expected —
select DISTINCT ?s ?s2 ?o
    WHERE { 
        GRAPH <urn:model1>
        {
            ?s m:reflect ?o.
        }
        GRAPH <urn:model2>
        {
            ?s2 m:reflect ?o2.
        }

     FILTER(str(?o) = str(?o2))
    }

For both graphs, strlen() and datatype() returns correct results (the same length and http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string).
And finally if the following modification of the filter is used —
FILTER( ?o = str(?o2))

— then the query runs forever.

If I understand your situation correctly, a better title might be, "Can I force all RDF string literals to be in the same encoding in the quad store, when loading some graphs via Jena, others via Conductor, others other ways? or convert all string literals to the same encoding after such bulk loading?"

In principle, the ultimate goal is indeed that - to have the same encoding of literals, regardless the method of loading. But I am also curious -what is the reason that literals have different encoding  if originally they were loaded from ttl files with the same UTF8 encoding and no any explicit encoding conversion was specified ?
And a little more -- why different encodings may lead to infinite queries ?

There are some known bugs around xsd:string and rdf:langString (see https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/428#issuecomment-1026825894 ). Maybe this is another occurrence of that. Did you check wether one of the literals has a language tag (even if this should not be the case for xsd:string)?

Yes, I checked language tags - they are missed in both cases.

If you do something like BIND ("ROAM-1234" AS ?o) at the top, does it find either triple? This looks more like a bug in the internal query engine than an "encoding".

The variant above with BIND does not returns expected result eighter.

Could you report this to the Virtuoso Open Source project?
